# setting an appropriate PATH for one user

Tags: linux, path, home-directory

I'm new to linux, and am taking a course that requires me to do the following:

1. Creating a login name
2. Establishing appropriate group(s)
3. Creating the home directory
4. Creating the login shell
5. Establishing a pass word for the user
6. Setting an appropriate PATH
7. Placing appropriate files in the home directory

This is what I have done so far, but I'm not sure about my home directory and PATH...

```
[root@Server ~]# useradd -gusers -s/bin/shell -p1234 -d/home/group -m userid
[root@CentosStudentSvr ~]# usermod -m -d/homedir/ userid
```

What I should I do for my PATH?

Comment: This is homework, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

I assume by 'PATH' you are referring to the environment variable `$PATH`.
If so, you would want to set and export in a configuration file.
This could be done in `/etc/profile` to affect all users, or in `~/.profile` for an individual user.

You could add the following:

```
PATH=$PATH:/data/myscripts:/some/other/dir
export PATH
```

Where

- `$PATH` preserves anything already set to the PATH.
- `:` separates entries.
- And the two directories are examples.

<sup>**Note:** this is a little bash biased, so It may be slightly different if you use another shell</sup>

Comment: He can also include `~/bin` into the per-user config. That would comply with _g)_ and is standard in some distros, too.